# How to Open multiple gmail accounts without logging out from the old one

Tags: gmail, accounts

How can i Open multiple gmail accounts without logging out from the old one in chrome browser

Comment: This sounds like a Super User question, let's migrate you over there for better help.

Comment: someone please close; not programming related

Answer (score 0):

Before you use to use private browsing mode but going forward.......  you can use multiple login feature provided by Google, which will allow you to have multiple accounts login to the same browser.

You can read the complete details here about how to do this.
[Google Multiple Sign-in option](http://www.buzzingup.com/2010/08/google-rolling-out-multiple-sign-in-now/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use incognito windows (shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+N). For every incognito **window** (not **tab**), you can log into one Gmail account.